# PostgreSQL ignoring null values when using filter as not in array

Tags: postgresql

Consider:

```
SELECT * FROM Entity e WHERE e.Status <> ANY(ARRAY[1,2,3]);
```

Here *Status* is a nullable integer column. Using the above query, I am unable to fetch the records whose status value is NULL.

```
SELECT * FROM Entity e WHERE (e.Status is NULL OR e.Status = 4);
```

This query does the trick. Why was the first query not working as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NULL kinda means "unknown", so the expressions

```
NULL = NULL
```

and

```
NULL != NULL
```

are neither true nor false, they're NULL. Because it is not known whether an "unknown" value is equal or unequal to another "unknown" value.

Since `<> ANY` uses an equality test, if the value searched in the array is NULL, then the result will be NULL.

So your second query is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It is spelled out in the docs [Array ANY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.30.16):

> If the array expression yields a null array, the result of ANY will be null. If the left-hand expression yields null, the result of ANY is ordinarily null (though a non-strict comparison operator could possibly yield a different result). Also, if the right-hand array contains any null elements and no true comparison result is obtained, the result of ANY will be null, not false (again, assuming a strict comparison operator). This is in accordance with SQL's normal rules for Boolean combinations of null values.

FYI:

`e.Status is NULL OR e.Status = 4`

can be shortened to:

`e_status IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 4`

per [Comparison operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-comparison.html).